# Iron Router Progress and Meteor 0.8

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to upgrade iron-router-progress with Meteor 0.8 and its new Blaze engine but I'm getting some problems. Iron-router-progress does not appear:

```
mrt remove iron-router-progress
```

And then, in my smart.json, I have added the following lines and run mrt update.

```
{
    "packages": {
        "iron-router-progress": {
            "git": "https://github.com/Multiply/iron-router-progress.git",
            "branch": "blaze-integration"
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works as expected:

```
✓ iron-router-progress
    branch: https://github.com/Multiply/iron-router-progress.git#blaze-integration
```

But when I'm running meteor, I can't see the #iron-router-progress div. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Give this a shot,`meteor remove iron-router-progress,
rm -rf packages/iron-router-progress,
mrt update,
mrt add iron-router-progress`

Comment: Okay, that seems to work better. I can now see the #iron-router-progress div. But the plugin doesn't work. It seems to be not up to date with the new iron router package. That's why I was using the blaze integration branch (but with this branch, the div doesn't even appear).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The issue has been solved](https://github.com/Multiply/iron-router-progress/issues/20).

Iron-router-progress is now perfectly working with blaze.

Answer (score 0):

No its not.

```
quackadmin@quack:~/quack$ sudo meteor
[[[[[ ~/quack ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Meteor 0.8.3 is available. Update this project with 'meteor update'.
=> Started MongoDB.
=> Errors prevented startup:

While building package `iron-dynamic-template`:
error: no such package: 'blaze'

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

Comment: It's because you are using the new released meteor 0.8.3. Downgrade to 0.8.2 or wait for a fix. (Check the repo on github)